# How to reorder method execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

How can i change the order of method exuction

i.e i have sperate logic in each method to determine one parameter

eg:

```
bool istype1 = checkfortype1(input);

if(!istype1)
bool istype2 = checkfortype2(input);

if(!istype2)
bool istype3 = checkfortype3(input);

if(!istype3)
bool istype4 = checkfortype4(input);

if(!istype4)
bool istype5 = checkfortype5(input);
```

the moment any one value is true i will stop checking for others.

the implemention for checkfortype1,checkfortype2 is totally different except it returns bool.

Now, i have my prediction order to determine which one to check first, to avoid unncessary check.
eg: {type2,type4,type1,type3,type5};

now i want to execute the method above in this order, how can i achive this using c# and/or Task

```
bool istype2 = checkfortype2(input);

if(!istype2)
bool istype4 = checkfortype4(input);

if(!istype4)
bool istype1 = checkfortype1(input);

if(!istype4)
bool istype3 = checkfortype3(input);

if(!istype3)
bool istype5 = checkfortype5(input);
```

Comment: I would say, create a list of functions of type Func, that way you can loop through the list and activate in any order you want

Comment: Honestly, I think your original code is fine. It is clear and easy to read (I mean the variable names are terrible, but I assume that is just for demo purposes). You could introduced `Task`s if you want to, but that may well reduce overall system performance (since presumably you want to check multiple conditions at once).

Comment: @mjwills, nope, i dont want to check all at once, the main intention is to avoid unnessary check,the implementaion of each "checkfortype" is really heavy.

Comment: In that case, I'd stick with what you have.

Comment: but i need to change the order of execution, based on priority

Comment: Are you saying today the order might be A, B, C and tomorrow it might be B, A, C?

Answer (score 1):

Create collection of functions and corresponding type

```
var all = new (string Name, Func<string> Check)[]
{
    ("type1", checkfortype2),
    ("type4", checkfortype4),
    ("type3", checkfortype3),
    ("type5", checkfortype5),
};

var foundType = all
    .Where(type => type.Check(input))
    .Select(type => type.Name)
    .DefaultIfEmpty("None")
    .First();

Console.WriteLine($"Input is of type: {foundType.Name}");
```

Chain of methods `Where.Select` will be executed until first check returns `true`, after successful check other checks will be "ignored".